# Digital pen or smart pen which has support for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hardware, usb-drive, wacom, input

I am looking for a digital pen to take handwritten notes which can be later transferred to computer to edit or save.

All the available digital pens come with their own software and they support windows and mac only.

I do not want to use windows to use the digital pen.

Please suggest a digital pen which supports Ubuntu with some tweaks or third party apps.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I found looking around on the Linux Hardware Compatibility List (HCL) is the Waltop QPad which is also sold by Aiptek under the designation "Aiptek HyperPen Mini".

No personal experience, the post is from 2010, so I advise you to start an e-mail campaign on Linux to the providers of the other digital pens that are around...  Maybe one will bite! :(